# Generators of a Dihedral Group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, dihedral-groups

Let $D_4=\{ 1,r,r^2,r^3,s, sr, sr^2, sr^3\}$.
I want to show that $<s> $ is a normal subgroup of $<s,r^2>$ but $<s>$ is not a normal subgroup of $D_{4}$.

I think $<s> = \{1,s\}$ and $<s,r^2> = \{1,s, sr^2,r^2 \}$

$<s>$ is a subgroup because it contains the identity element and is a group.
I want to show it is a normal subgroup of $<s,r^2>$. 
So, I should find the left and right cosets.

$$\begin{array}{ll}
\mbox{Left Cosets} & \mbox{ Right cosets}\\
1<s> = \{1,s\} & <s>1 = \{1,s\} \\
s<s> = \{s,1 \} & <s>s = \{s,1\} \\
sr^2<s> = \{sr^2, sr^2s\} & <s>sr^2 = \{sr^2, ssr^2\} = \{sr^2,r^2 \}\\ 
r^2<s> = \{ r^2,r^2s\} & <s>r^2 = \{r^2,sr^2\}
\end{array}$$

By what i've written, the left and right cosets are not exactly the same. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please write presentation of $D_4$. What are $s$ and $r$

Comment: I"m not sure what you mean by presentation, but $D_4 = \{1,r,r^2,r^3, s,rs,r^2s,r^3s\}$ and $r,s$ denote rotations and reflections respectively.

Comment: Hint: Recall the identity $r^2s=sr^2$.

Comment: @BenS. Ah yes, that identity I was using (I apologize for not making clear which coset was the one troubling me). My trouble is with $sr^2<s>$ and $<s>sr^2$. I do not think $sr^2 s = r^2$.  And yes, that is what I meant in my definition. I was not aware there were others.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth It seems like the OP means the standard presentation for $D_4$ (for example, the one found in Dummit and Foote): $D_4=\langle r,s|r^4=s^2=1,rs=sr^{-1}\rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the discussion in the comments as to where the confusion lies:

$sr^2s=s(r^2s)=s(sr^2)=ssr^2=s^2r^2=r^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Here $s$ and $r$ are not so good in the sense that $sr\neq rs$; but they are not so bad in the sense that *we have*, $sr=r^3s$ (and $rs=sr^3$). Can you use this one to check whether each left coset is the "next" right coset?